# Vba rs.execute (Parameter Query)

Tags: sql, vba, recordset

Please, could you tell me how is the sentence to execute a SQL Query using vba? (With parameters)
I'm trying to do this :

- First prepare a sub to call the function Arir_Recordset:

  Public Sub Retriev_rs()

  ```
  Dim Query As String
  Query = "SELECT * FROM  '" & Table & "'  WHERE DNI = '" & DNI & "'  "
  Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset


  Open_Connection---- Works well!

  Set rs2 = Abrir_Recordset(Query, "PRODUCTOS_CLIENTESBCO", "00000098687")


  End Sub
  ```

---

- The Function:

  Public Function Abrir_Recordset(Query As String, Table As String, DNI As String) As ADODB.Recordset

  ```
  Dim comm As ADODB.Command

  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
  rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic

  Set rs = conn.Execute(QUERY)

  Set Abrir_Recordset = rs


  End Function
  ```

---

- Issue:

It's not recognising the Query. It says :

Incorrect sintax near "

It's reading:

```
 - "SELECT * FROM  ''  WHERE DNI = ''  "
```

Of course... it isn't write well the Query. Could you help me ??

Many thanks!!!

Comment: You need to either assign or pass in as arguments the *Table* and *DNI* variables.

Comment: See [Creating parameterized commands](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado/12354/creating-parameterized-commands#t=201609272324299867052).

Comment: Thanks! It´s working now : :

Query = "Select * from  " & Tabla & "  where DNI = '" & DNI & "'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Done... passing parameters to this Function works well :

```
Public Function Abrir_Recordset(Tabla As String, DNI As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim comm As ADODB.Command

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic

Query = "Select * from  " & Tabla & "  where DNI = '" & DNI & "'"

Abrir_Conexion


Set rs = conn.Execute(Query)

Set Abrir_Recordset = rs


End Function
```